# Image in ImageView disappear

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

In `MainActivtiy`, we use `Glide` to load URL image into `imgSignature`.

When `imgSignature` clicked, a custom dialog pop out and it will display the image in `imgSign`. Our problem is when we clicked the done button in the custom dialog, the image inside `imgSignature` become empty and getting this toast message `bgDrawable null`.

Why image in imgSignature will gone ?

```
      lateinit var signDialog: Dialog

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            signDialog = Util().dialogSignature(getActivity())

            var mSignature = signature(activity, null)
            signDialog.relativeLayout2.addView(mSignature)

            var image: Bitmap? = null

            if (obj?.signature_image?.url != null) {
                Glide.with(activity)
                    .load(obj?.signature_image?.url.toString())
                    .into(imgSignature)
            }

            imgSignature.setOnClickListener {
                signDialog.show()
                if (obj?.signature_image?.url != " ") {
                    Glide.with(activity)
                        .load(obj?.signature_image?.url.toString())
                        .into(signDialog.imgSign);
                }
            }

            signDialog.doneTxt.setOnClickListener {
                signDialog.dismiss()
                imgSignature.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromView(mSignature))
            }
    }

 fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        val returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(250, 250, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        //Bind a canvas to it
        val canvas = Canvas(returnedBitmap)
        //Get the view's background
        val bgDrawable = view.background
        if (bgDrawable != null) {
            longToast("bgDrawable not null")
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas)
        }
        else {
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
            // draw the view on the canvas
            view.draw(canvas)
            longToast("bgDrawable null")
        }
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap
    }
}
```

**Util**

```
 fun dialogSignature(context: Context?):Dialog{

        var dialog = Dialog(context)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_signature)
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        return dialog
    }
```

**dialog_signature**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="230dp"
                                             android:orientation="vertical"
                                             android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@color/colorPrimaryShadow"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout2" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Place Signature"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                  android:id="@+id/doneTxt"
                  android:text="Done"
                  android:textColor="@color/colorDarkBlue"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout1" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:id="@+id/imgSign"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
              android:textColor="@color/colorDarkBlue"
              android:text="Clear" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              android:id="@+id/clearTxt"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Happy chinese new year to all chinese

**Edit**

I tried @rafa answer, but get this exception

```
cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
```

on line

```
val bgDrawable = (view as ImageView).drawable
```

**signture**

```
inner class signature(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {
        private val paint = Paint()
        private val path = Path()

        private var lastTouchX: Float = 0.toFloat()
        private var lastTouchY: Float = 0.toFloat()
        private val dirtyRect = RectF()

        private val STROKE_WIDTH = 5f
        private val HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2

        init {
            paint.setAntiAlias(true)
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK)
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND)
            paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH)
        }

        override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
        }

        override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            val eventX = event.x
            val eventY = event.y
//            mGetSign.setEnabled(true)

            when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY)
                    lastTouchX = eventX
                    lastTouchY = eventY
                    return true
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE,

                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY)
                    val historySize = event.historySize
                    for (i in 0 until historySize) {
                        val historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i)
                        val historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i)
                        expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY)
                        path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY)
                    }
                    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY)
                }
                else -> {
                    debug("Ignored touch event: $event")
                    return false
                }
            }

            invalidate(
                (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH).toInt(),
                (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH).toInt(),
                (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH).toInt(),
                (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH).toInt()
            )

            lastTouchX = eventX
            lastTouchY = eventY

            return true
        }

        private fun debug(string: String) {
//            Log.v("log_tag", string)
        }

        private fun expandDirtyRect(historicalX: Float, historicalY: Float) {
            if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
                dirtyRect.left = historicalX
            } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
                dirtyRect.right = historicalX
            }

            if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
                dirtyRect.top = historicalY
            } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
                dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY
            }
        }

        private fun resetDirtyRect(eventX: Float, eventY: Float) {
            dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX)
            dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX)
            dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY)
            dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY)
        }

    }
```

Comment: what does mSignature variable hold? what is this method signature(activity, null)? @Hoo

Comment: Don't use getBitmapFromView. 
In the first time load with glilde enable image caching using 
`Glide.with(activity) 
.load(obj?.signature_image?.url.toString())
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
 .into(signDialog.imgSign);`

 just use Glide to load the image in the imageview  the second time and it will be loaded from the cache.  Read more about it here https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html

Comment: in second time how to load from cache ?

Comment: Updated the answer @Hoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your mSignature doesnot hold any Image, so returns null when you try to retrieve Image( or background) from it. Removing the *mSignature* with *imgSignature* should work. But still am not sure why you need signature class.

```
lateinit var signDialog: Dialog

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        signDialog = Util().dialogSignature(getActivity())

        //var mSignature = signature(activity, null)
        //signDialog.relativeLayout2.addView(mSignature)

        var image: Bitmap? = null

        if (obj?.signature_image?.url != null) {
            Glide.with(activity)
                .load(obj?.signature_image?.url.toString())
                .into(imgSignature)
        }

        imgSignature.setOnClickListener {
            signDialog.show()
            if (obj?.signature_image?.url != " ") {
                Glide.with(activity)
                    .load(obj?.signature_image?.url.toString())
                    .into(signDialog.imgSign);
            }
        }

        signDialog.doneTxt.setOnClickListener {
            signDialog.dismiss()



            // code change goes here imgSignature
            imgSignature.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromView(imgSignature))
        }
}
```

You are using *view.background* instead of *view.drawable* as Imageview is set with src attribute by glide. And you have to setBounds for the drawable. Please find the changes below.

```
fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        val returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(250, 250, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        //Bind a canvas to it
        val canvas = Canvas(returnedBitmap)


        //Get the Imageview's src drawable
        val bgDrawable = (view as ImageView).drawable


        if (bgDrawable != null) {
            bgDrawable.setbounds(10,10,240,240); // setting bounds with padding of 10

            longToast("bgDrawable not null")
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas)
        }
        else {
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
            // draw the view on the canvas
            view.draw(canvas)
            longToast("bgDrawable null")
        }
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap
    }
}
```

Happy New Year :)

Comment: cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView

Comment: what does mSignature variable hold? what is this method signature(activity, null)?

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check @Hoo